# Product Identifiers Are Valid On One Phone But Not Another

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

I've begun testing the In App Purchase functionality of my phone.  It works great on my phone, every product id I submit works fine and comes back as valid, but as soon as I tested it on my coworkers phone, each product id came back as invalid.

I'm probably over looking something and I've followed a bunch of tutorials online, but is there any reason for storekit to reject valid product id's on one phone and accept them on another?

Note that I've ensured that there are no parental control settings on the other device.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured this one out.  After testing product id's on every other device I could find and not being able to recreate the invalid product id error, we removed the app from the bad phone, rebooted, reinstalled and everything is working fine again.

This was on iOS 4.2 and an iPhone 4 if anyone else come across this error again.

Comment: I had the same problem. Worked on my iPad, not on my iPhone 4. Delete, reboot & reinstall also worked for me.

Comment: I didn't have to reboot. However, I did back up my device first, then deleted and reinstalled, then restored from a backup, to preserve my app data.