# iPhone: Cannot test InAppPurchase in sandbox after it is approved

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have a free iPhone App which uses in app purchase. I tested my first InAppPurchase with sandbox environment and it worked fine. After the InAppPurchase was approved and worked fine in App store, I added several new InAppPurchases in iTunes Connect and tried to test them in the sandbox environment. However I could not find these new InAppPurchases in my app.

The following is the code I uses to get InAppPurchase products:

```
//....

SKProductsRequest *prodRequest= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:
                [NSSet setWithObject: prod]];
prodRequest.delegate = self;
[prodRequest start];

//....

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    int count = [response.products count];

    NSLog(@"number of products:%d",count);
    for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {
        SKProduct* product = [response.products objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"product %d:id=%@ title=%@ desc=%@ price=%@", i, product.productIdentifier, product.localizedTitle, 
             product.localizedDescription,
             product.price);
    }
}
```

If I use the old InAppPurchase product id I can get it, but if I use any newly created product id I got count==0.

From what I saw, I guess may app may not be running in the sandbox environment after my first InAppPurchase was approved, but this is just a guess, because I don't know how to check if my app is in sandbox mode or not.

I searched Internet about this issue and tried the following:
1. created a new version of my app, uploaded it to iTunes connect, and rejected the binary. no use
2. deleted all my provisioning profiles and created new ones. no use
3. created an app id for my app in developer provisioning portal and created provisioning profile for that id and used it in Xcode. no use

My Xcode version was 3.2.5. I upgraded it to 4 but this did not fix the problem.

I am wondering if any one else has seen this issue and found a solution. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. Fortunately i have several devices i can work with, it works on some but not on others. So try it on another device. I have also seen people say that doing a complete reset to their device solved this issue.

Comment: Thanks Zaky. I have two devices. One I have used before for testing my first InAppPurchase, the other one is new, but neither works.

Answer (score 2):

OK I came across this post and got some hint:

[Product Identifiers Are Valid On One Phone But Not Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360830/product-identifiers-are-valid-on-one-phone-but-not-another)

I just deleted the app from my iPod Touch, did not reboot, then tried to run my app from Xcode again, and it worked. I guess there was some states saved together with the app which determines whether to use sandbox environment for InAppPurchase or not. Although I could run my newly compiled binary without deleting the old app, I could not get rid of some old state which caused the app not running in the sandbox environment. That is what caused the problem. The solution is to delete the old app from the device before running newly compiled binary.